# Accessing global variable javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download a web-page using nodejs, javascript. However it seems to have a inifinite loop. Why?

```
var downloadFinished = false;

var downloadPage = function(url,file) {
  rest.get(url).on('complete', function(result) {
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    console.log('Error:', result.message);
  } else {
    fs.writeFileSync(file, result, 'utf8');
    downloadFinished = true;
   }   
  }); 
};

if(require.main == module) {
    downloadPage('http://google.com', 'new.html');
    while(!downloadFinished) {
       // wait till download finished.
    } 
    // do other stuff make sure download is finished to 'new.html'
}
```

Comment: this is begging for a callback instead of infinite while looping.

Comment: @pennstatephil What you mean?

Comment: pass in a callback function that you can call when the download is complete. Similar to a `success` callback when using jquery's `$.ajax` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded, if you have a loop like:

```
while(!downloadFinished) {

}
```

that loop will keep running forever and no other function will run (your `.on('complete'` callback can't execute until the while loop finishes, because of the single-threaded nature of Javascript, so it won't ever finish since you don't set `downloadFinished = true` inside that loop or use a `break` statement).

To work around this, you can do all your other stuff in a callback which you don't call until the download completed:

```
var downloadPage = function(url, file, callback) {
  rest.get(url).on('complete', function(result) {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      console.log('Error:', result.message);
    } else {

      /* Don't use writeFileSync, unless you want to block your server,
        from handling any requests at all until the disk IO completes

        fs.writeFileSync(file, result, 'utf8');
        callback();
      */
      fs.writeFile(file, result, 'utf8', callback);
    }   
  }); 
};

if(require.main == module) {
    downloadPage('http://google.com', 'new.html', function after_download(){
        // do other stuff make sure download is finished to 'new.html'
    });
}
```

Comment: @celebisait You're better off using `fs.writeFile` instead of `fs.writeFileSync` as well, so I just changed that in my answer. `fs.writeFile` will call your callback when it finishes writing the file to the filesystem, and your server is free to handle other requests, since it's not using a `synchronous` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you call that `while(!downloadFinished)` it is set to false so you are basically doing `while(true)`.

### Option 1

You can use a callback instead of a while loop.

```
var successCallback = function() {
 //do stuff here.
};

var downloadPage = function(url, file, callback) {
  rest.get(url).on('complete', function(result) {
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    console.log('Error:', result.message);
  } else {
    fs.writeFile(file, result, 'utf8', callback);
   }   
  }); 
};

if(require.main == module) {
    downloadPage('http://google.com', 'new.html', successCallback);
}
```

### Option 2

Check out [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) they will really help you here. You could use [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) a nice Promise library you can just add to your package dependencies.

Comment: I actually am setting `downloadFinished=true` when it finishes.

Comment: You already got my upvote, but note that the OP mentioned node.js. I don't think they're running this in a browser. I would recommend [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) for option 2 as it is really an awesome Promise library.

Comment: @Paulpro Nice i have actually been looking for a nice promise library for node. I have updated my answer to include it!